# List all UIViewControllers of project

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, automation, uikit, automated-tests

For automation of screenshot capture, and for testing purposes, I would like to **list all `UIViewController` classes of my project**.
I do not wish to get a list of all UIKit view controllers, I just want the ones I created in my project.

I want to do this in Objective-C code, at runtime, because I then will need to instantiate some of the listed classes.
For example, in my unit tests, I might want a test that assert that all UITableViewCell subclasses return the same height that the height of the item in the xib associated, and this object is not a UIView subclass but a UITableViewCell subclass.
An other intended use is to add to the documentation of the project a screenshot of all my `UIViewController` classes.

Note that this code will not be shipped to customer. It will only be used in testing and scripting on the developer machine.

I guess I could parse the files included in pbxproj, but that feels wrong and not robust.
A simple `ls *ViewController.h` on my project works too, but same feeling about it.
Any other idea?

Bonus if I can then extend this way on other classes, to for example get all the `UITableViewCells` I created, or all `UIViews`.

Comment: do you want to do it in the runtime environment (e.g. test module that links aginst your program) or create a OS X Application that parses your code?

Comment: @MartinUllrich at runtime (added the clarification to the question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using my [NSObject+Subclasses](https://gist.github.com/0xced/5107798) category, you can easily  get all subclasses of `UIViewController`.

To get **your** view controllers only, filter them like this:

```
NSSet *myViewControllerClasses = [[UIViewController subclasses_xcd] filteredSetUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return [[NSBundle bundleForClass:evaluatedObject] isEqual:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
}]];
```

Then you can do whatever you want with the content of `myViewControllerClasses` that contains `Class` objects.

Answer (score 1):

Using the runtime, it's a bit hard. You can use the definitions of `class_t` and `class_rw_t` (data-member of class objects) to explore subclass trees efficiently.

To filter your classes, you might need to look at the beginning of the class names (prefix) or maybe a base VC class if have created one for your project.

See [this article](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/01/getting-subclasses-of-objective-c-class.html)

Comment: Nice article, thank you. In the article, I didn't see any way to filter between UIKit and my classes. Did I miss something? Any take on that?